# android kernel modification to unlock the screen during boot

Tags: android, kernel, screen, unlock

When I boot the android, I want the screen to be unlocked automatically (and run an application) rather than me unlocking the screen .
Can anyone tell me where the kernel source code change has to be done to do so ?

---

The java code is here.. Can you please correct it

```
public class AddnumsActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String KEYGUARD_SERVICE = null;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            lock.disableKeyguard();
            if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {  
                Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, AddnumsActivity.class);  
                pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(pushIntent);  
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to do kernel changes for this. All you got to do is Create a boot complete Reciever and disable lock screen in it

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

And add below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

And your activity which needs to be shown at startup should act as home screen. Use below filter for your activity

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: where these changes has to be done ? in the application ? I even want to start an application after the screen is auto unlocked

Comment: there is one adb command to unlock the screen "adb shell input keyevent 82"

Comment: Yeah in the application, Your activity that needs to be started immediately should have the intent filter that is described above

Comment: keyevent 82 is just pressing menu, it cant unlock the screen

Comment: unlock I meant was by swiping from left to right (and not the key press to unlock)

Comment: application crashes as soon as I unlock the screen (unlock screen has to be done manually -> swipe from left to right)